# Google Keep won't load properly in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-keep

Google Keep will not function for me anymore in Firefox.

When I go to http://keep.google.com, as soon as the page finishes loading I get a little dialog that says

> You've been signed out. Please reload the page to sign in again and continue working.

With a button that says **Reload**. Clicking it reloads the page and it says the same thing.

I've tried logging out of Google and back in, tried deleting all history of the site, tried refreshing with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to bypass the cache, nothing seems to work.

Does anyone else have this problem? Is there a way to get Keep to work again?

Comment: Problem you are facing while logging into the google keep is that the data is not getting synced from the google to that particular account so only it is not able to receive the data for login.We request you to try after sometime and check whether you still have the problem.

Comment: This problem has been persistent for about a week now. I would think then too that logging out of the account and back in would've cleared up any issue, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOH! Stupid answer, but figured out what it was. I'm just posting it here in case someone else has this issue in the future.

For working with web services of one of our clients at work, I recently installed a Firefox plugin to modify the headers sent to websites, and add an `Authorization` header to all requests. Didn't occur to me till just now that that could be the issue.

Turned that off, and now Keep works as expected again! 
Yay!  :)