# Google Keep keeps signing me out

Tags: google-keep

Google Keep is not working. I keep getting this message even after I refresh and try logging back in

> You’ve been signed out. Please reload the page to sign in again and continue working

I have tried using different browsers, clearing my cache, restarting my mac and nothing seems to work.

[This solution did not help me:](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/70538/google-keep-wont-load-properly-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the inconvenience. Google Keep has a service issue at this moment. Google is investigating this issue to fix it.

[image: http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=43&iid=b998aa8f87fce743bbb9cf6d24921534]